# Window 10 pro version Docker installaion issues

Tags: docker, installation, window

I have window 10 Pro version also and already Virtual Box installed. I don't want to use new Virtual Box installed again. After installation virtual box not starting.
[image]

with following message
Running pre-create checks...
No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
Error with pre-create check: "Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest: dial tcp 192.30.253.116:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with both when I started the Docker Quick-start terminal it will give the message above as in question. OR If i used the Kitematic the following message.

```
Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer 
bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte 
Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert 
hat."],bugsnag.Notify: [bugsnag/payload.deliver: Post 
https://notify.bugsnag.com/: dial tcp 35.186.205.6:443: connectex: Ein 
Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer 
bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte 
Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat.],
```

Solution is to copy the ISO file (boot2docker.iso) created by installation at

C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox

TO

C:\Users\krishnav.docker\machine\cache

The iso file will be created in "Docker ToolBox" directory and looks to be error on copying after installation. After this Docker Quick Terminal was able to launch it and it was visible in Virtual BOX under "default" name.

Also remove all docker related Environment variable.
In Window 10 pro if you install "Docker for Window" you don't need virtual box and Hyper-V will be enabled but Virtual Box will be disabled, that I did not want. As I have had many Suse Installation there.

I had installed "Docker for Window" and it asked for disabling virtual box.
After this limitation, i uninstalled that, removed all Env variable created by it and installed Docker toolbox but disselected the Virtual Box

[image]

```
krishnav@XXXXX MINGW64 ~
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25
```